# Как исключить определенные картинки из location?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

Иметься такой `location`:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|png|bmp|pict|csv|doc|pdf|pls|ppt|tif|tiff|eps|ejs|swf|midi|mid|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|otf|svg|svgz|webp|docx|xlsx|xls|pptx|ps|class|jar)$ {
    expires modified 30d;
}
```

Как исключить, чтобы этот `location` не обрабатывал, например, one.png и two.png?
У меня единая точка входа, и try_files не находя файл передает запрос на index.php. Но location выше для статики, выше в приоритете. Эти две картинки, условно говоря, я генерирую php скриптом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если nginx поддерживает в регулярках просмотр вперед, то попробуйте так:

```
location ~* ^(?!one\.png|two\.png).+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|png|bmp|pict|csv|doc|pdf|pls|ppt|tif|tiff|eps|ejs|swf|midi|mid|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|otf|svg|svgz|webp|docx|xlsx|xls|pptx|ps|class|jar)$ {
    expires modified 30d;
}
```